# Angularjs, Creating Array from Object and Error: $rootScope:infdig

Tags: angularjs

My aim is to create an arrays from object(as table rows) but I get the $rootScope:infdig error.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.rows = {
"TableName": "TestTable",
"Rows": [{
    "Name": "Name1",
    "RowCells": [{
        "Y": 2001,
        "M": 164
    }, {
        "Y": 2002,
        "M": 178
    }, {
        "Y": 2003,
        "M": 188
    }, {
        "Y": 2007,
        "M": 295
    }, {
        "Y": 2008,
        "M": 316
    }, {
        "Y": 2009,
        "M": 328
    }]
}],
"Rows": [{
    "Name": "Name2",
    "RowCells": [{
        "Y": 2001,
        "M": 164
    }, {
        "Y": 2002,
        "M": 178
    }, {
        "Y": 2003,
        "M": 188
    }, {
        "Y": 2007,
        "M": 295
    }, {
        "Y": 2008,
        "M": 316
    }, {
        "Y": 2009,
        "M": 328
    }]
}],
"Rows": [{
    "Name": "Name3",
    "RowCells": [{
        "Y": 2001,
        "M": 164
    }, {
        "Y": 2002,
        "M": 178
    }, {
        "Y": 2003,
        "M": 188
    }, {
        "Y": 2007,
        "M": 295
    }, {
        "Y": 2008,
        "M": 316
    }, {
        "Y": 2009,
        "M": 328
    }]
}]
}

 $scope.rowCells = function () {
                var tableRowCollection = [];

                angular.forEach($scope.rows, function (item) {
                    var tableRow = [];
                    tableRow.push(item.Name);
                    angular.forEach(item.RowCells, function (i) {
                        tableRow.push(i.M);
                    });
                    tableRowCollection.push(tableRow);
                });
                return tableRowCollection ;
            };

 <div data-ng-repeat="r in rowCells()">{{r}}</div>
```

I have seen similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753014/angularjs-error-rootscopeinfdig) but that didn't help.
what am I missing or where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your rows array should be like this:

```
$scope.rows = {
"TableName": "TestTable",
"Rows": [{
    "Name": "Name1",
    "RowCells": [{
        "Y": 2001,
        "M": 164
    }, {
        "Y": 2002,
        "M": 178
    }, {
        "Y": 2003,
        "M": 188
    }, {
        "Y": 2007,
        "M": 295
    }, {
        "Y": 2008,
        "M": 316
    }, {
        "Y": 2009,
        "M": 328
    }]
}, {
    "Name": "Name2",
    "RowCells": [{
        "Y": 2001,
        "M": 164
    }, {
        "Y": 2002,
        "M": 178
    }, {
        "Y": 2003,
        "M": 188
    }, {
        "Y": 2007,
        "M": 295
    }, {
        "Y": 2008,
        "M": 316
    }, {
        "Y": 2009,
        "M": 328
    }]
}, {
    "Name": "Name3",
    "RowCells": [{
        "Y": 2001,
        "M": 164
    }, {
        "Y": 2002,
        "M": 178
    }, {
        "Y": 2003,
        "M": 188
    }, {
        "Y": 2007,
        "M": 295
    }, {
        "Y": 2008,
        "M": 316
    }, {
        "Y": 2009,
        "M": 328
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: you are right, there was a mistake in my object but this is only slipped in while I was creating the example, the real object is ok.

Answer (score 0):

As Staskus suggested, you have to change your array. Your `foreach` loop should be as below:

```
angular.forEach($scope.rows.Rows, function(item) {
    var tableRow = [];
    tableRow.push(item.Name);
    angular.forEach(item.RowCells, function(i) {
        tableRow.push(i.M);
    });
    tableRowCollection.push(tableRow);
});
```

Comment: Yes the $scope.rows should have been $scope.rows.Rows in this example. The real object I'm working with is coming in from the api via ajax and has been set as $scope.rows = response.data.Rows. I'm still getting the  Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Comment: $rootScope:infdig error comes if there is an infinite loop where model is getting updated based on view data and view data is triggering model updates. HTML that you have provided includes only partial. If you can provide full html then it will be easy to identify. Please check this link for infinite error :https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: Yes, I've seen that link and figured out that it is <div data-ng-repeat="r in rowCells()">{{r}}</div> part that causing problems. I ended up taking different approach.